# Calculation in retrieved JSON API data

Tags: javascript, php, json

Here is my code I need how to add a percentage or number to each value in total field I have tried a lot but nothing works.

```
<?php

$json=file_get_contents("http://www.upliftinghumanity.net/edd-api/sales/?key=75caa8cb60362c89e6ac2b62730cd516&token=6547d40b82cecb81cb7b0ec928554a9e&number=-1");
$data =  json_decode($json);
extract(json_decode($json, true));

if (count($data->sales)) {
    // Open the table
    echo "<table>";


    // Cycle through the array
    foreach ($data->sales as $idx => $sales)
 {

        // Output a row
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>$sales->total</td>";
        echo "<td>$sales->total+3 </td>";
        echo "<td>$sales->gateway</td>";
    echo "<td>$sales->email</td>";
    echo "<td>$sales->transaction_id</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }

    // Close the table
    echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Twwv0.png)

Comment: "Trying a lot" isn't a question.  Post what have you tried, and what happened, and ask a question about whatever you don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can't perform php arithmetic operations which its been qouted as a string, you can probably use the "{$sales->data+3}" but it is always advisable to do thr calculation outside the string as this is only a pseudo code "{$sales->data+3}" and may not work even if you include the curly braces

Comment: so how would i add a number ?

Comment: You can add it before echoing it out as a string for example $somevar = $sales->data+1;   echo "blahh $somevar"; or  echo "blahh {$somevar}";

Comment: You can also do it with the concatenation when using brackets: `"blah blah ".($sales->data + 3)." more blah"`

Comment: @Ezekiel the problem is solved what you suggest. i was missing some basic stuff . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can add it before echoing it out as a string for example $somevar = $sales->data+1; echo "blahh $somevar"; or echo "blahh {$somevar}";

@Ezekiel the problem is solved what you suggest. i was missing some basic stuff . Thanks –